# Replace certain element in only first line of the text file

Tags: python, file-io, replace

I have a text file and would like to replace certain elements which is "NaN".

I usually have used `file.replace` function for change NaNs with a certain number through entire text file.
Now, I would like to replace NaNs with a certain number in only first line of text file, not whole text.
Would you give me a hint for this problem?

Comment: There is no `file.replace` function. YOu should post your attempted code so far so that we can point you to what's wrong with your code. Based on what I understand of your question thus far, I'd recommend using `myFile = open('path/to/file'); firstLine = myFile.readline(); newFirstLine = firstLine.replace('oldValue', 'newValue'); rest = ''.join(myFile.readlines(); myFile.close(); myFile = open('path/to/file', 'w'); myFile.write(newFirstLine+rest); myFile.close()`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget - the 2nd half of that comment looks like an answer to me.

Comment: Thank you very much inspectorG4dget, your answer also seems to bewhat I look for. I will let you know after I tried.

Comment: Thank you both inspectorG4dget and Rob It really works very well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only read the whole file, call .replace() for the first line and write it to the new file.

```
with open('in.txt') as fin:
    lines = fin.readlines()
lines[0] = lines[0].replace('old_value', 'new_value')

with open('out.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for line in lines:
        fout.write(line)
```

If your file isn't really big, you can use just .join():

```
with open('out.txt', 'w') as fout:
    fout.write(''.join(lines))
```

And if it is really big, you would probably better read and write lines simultaneously.

Comment: Isaac *might* be able to avoid rewriting the whole file.  See my answer for details.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski your solution is OK only for strings of equal length, they are here sure not.

Answer (score 3):

You can hack this provided you accept a few constraints.  The replacement string needs to be of equal length to the original string. If the replacement string is shorter than the original, pad the shorter string with spaces to make it of equal length (this only works if extra spaces in your data is acceptable).  If the replacement string is longer than the original you can not do the replacement in place and need to follow Harold's answer.

```
with open('your_file.txt', 'r+') as f:
    line = next(f) # grab first line
    old = 'NaN'
    new = '0  ' # padded with spaces to make same length as old 
    f.seek(0) # move file pointer to beginning of file
    f.write(line.replace(old, new))
```

This will be fast on any length file.

Comment: It needs to be `'r+'` instead of `'rw'`. Besides that thanks! This is much better for larger files.

Comment: @skjerns Thanks for the correction on the file mode.