# Converting text file to .xlsx in python

Tags: python, pandas

```
10 4

0 0 0 0

0 0 1 0

1 0 2 0

2 2 0 1

0 0 1 1

0 1 2 1

1 1 1 1

1 2 2 0

0 0 1 0

2 0 1 0
```

I want to read the above text file store this in xlsx format. But with my code whole row is stored in same cell. But I want them in different cells. Each item is space seperated.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('input.txt')

df.to_excel('test2.xls',index=False)
```

Expected result: Each item stored in different cell.

Note that the first row only has 2 elements.

Comment: Pass `sep=' '` into `pandas.read_csv`

Comment: Hi clade, 1st row have only 2 elements So all the rows are becoming 2 elements

Comment: Add 0 0 to the first row? Or write more code to ensure all rows have four elements?

Comment: what about change the top to `0 1 0 4`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the delimiter to be a space instead of a comma.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("input.txt", header=None, delim_whitespace=True, names=['a','b','c','d'])

df.to_excel('test2.xls',index=False, header=None)
```

Notice that I used `delim_whitespace=True` to tell pandas to use spaces instead of commas. Also since you have only 2 elements in the first row I name the columns to let pandas know that you expect 4 columns.

Comment: But first line is being removed or else what is the code to fill next 2 empty spaces  in first linewith 0's

Comment: what about `shutil`? @SAITEJA

Comment: first line with 10 4 disappeared

Comment: First line isn't being removed. The df puts 2 NaN values in columns 3 and 4. and then when you save to excel it disappears. If you want to store 0s you can transform the NaNs to 0s before saving the excel file

Comment: all the values stored in first line are 0's

Comment: 0 0 0 0
  first line is in this way

Comment: @SAITEJA I asked you to try `shutil` to do `line = "0 " + line` and you can save that new one onto new text. do you want that?

Comment: Just copied the input into a file and I can see 10 4 as the first row in the excel file

Comment: @SAITEJA Also if you don't want that, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15468992/replace-certain-element-in-only-first-line-of-the-text-file/15469189

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

with open('input.txt') as fin:
    lines = fin.readlines()
lines[0] = "0 " + lines[0] + " 0"

with open('input2.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for line in lines:
        fout.write(line)

df = pd.read_csv('input2.txt', header=None, delim_whitespace=True) 

df.to_excel('output.xls', index=False, header=None)
```

So this creates a unnecessary `input2.txt` and this should work assuming your first line is your first row in the text.

But what it is changing is that `10 4` becomes `0 10 4 0` so this has 4 elements in it.

I did `delim_whitespace=True` for `read_csv()` because it tells pandas not to do it in commas but in whitespaces.

At the top, I opened the file, used `lines = fin.readlines()` and then did `lines[0]` because `lines` is a array and the first element is `arr[0]`. Then I put the 0 and a space at the left and a space then a 0 at the right. And then I wrote a new text and wrote all the lines inside by using a `for` loop.

Finally I plug that into the `read_csv()` function  and apply `to_excel()` with the parameters and one more parameter that I talked about above.

It's okay if this creates a new text file, and that the text thing is not at all pandas. This should be working and I have not checked yet so I don't know if this works or not.

Hope this helps!